# VK API: Standalone token для сайта, как получить?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Необходимо использовать методы vk api, доступные только для standalone-приложений и авторизации через [implicit_flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user), например [wall.post](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post)

Согласно документации, для нормального получения token (который реально будет работать с данным методом) в redirect_uri необходимо указать blank.html, тогда сам токен будет доступен в итоговом окне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вытащить токен из url средствами браузера невозможно, и казалось единственный способ - просить пользователя копировать его вручную, НО!

Существует масса сайтов (сервисы автопостинга), которые каким то образом обходят данное ограничение, причем для авторизации они используют даже не standalone-приложения.
Вот [примеры](https://crmindex.ru/ratings/servisu_otlozhennogo_postinga), вот [пример окна авторизации](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3747148&scope=photos,groups,offline,wall,video&redirect_uri=https://prostoposting.ru/vk/login/redirect&response_type=code&state=https://prostoposting.ru/vk/schedule&revoke=1) на одном из них.

Практически уверен, что данные сайты не могут иметь каких-то "особых" разрешений со стороны администрации ВКонтакте, тем не менее это не мешает им получать доступ к (казалось бы) закрытым методам.

Надеюсь, кто то подскажет "секрет", как они это делают?
Спасибо!

Comment: Показанный вами пример — не standalone-приложение, а подключенный сайт, вот и весь "секрет" https://vk.com/app3747148

Comment: да, но токен полученный в таких приложениях не имеет доступа к методу